# particular subset of a real normed space

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $A$  a not empty subset of  a  normed  space $E$,  with $\dim E<\infty$, such that $ A+A=A$,  can we say  that  $0\in \overline{A}$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Is $E$ a vector space? And are the scalars R or C?

Comment: Your conjecture is false. Find some counterexample $A\subset E:=\Bbb R.$ But [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: The conjecture is true if $\dim E=1$.

Comment: $E=\mathbb R$,  
1) $A\subset \mathbb R^+$. $a=\inf A$ exists. Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in A$ such that $x\leq a+\varepsilon$. But, $x=x_1+x_2$ with $x_1,x_2\in A$ then $2a\leq x_1+x_2=x<a+\varepsilon\Rightarrow a<\varepsilon$ therefore $a=0\in\overline{A }$.  
2) $A\subset \mathbb R^-$ , $-A\subset \mathbb R^+ \Rightarrow 0\in\overline{-A}\Rightarrow 0\in\overline{A}$.  
3) $A\cap \mathbb R^{+*}\not=\emptyset$ and $A\cap \mathbb R^{-*}\not=\emptyset$ . Then $a=\inf A\cap \mathbb R^{+*}$ and $b=\sup A\cap \mathbb R^{-*}$ exist and $ab\leq 0$. So  $A=a\mathbb Z$ or $overline{A}=\mathbb R$.